# Put a button on top of a google map

Tags: google-maps, button, overlay

I would like to put a button on top of a Google Map next to the Map, Satelite and Hybrid buttons.

I was wondering if its possible and how would be the best way to do it?

So ideas I have are overlaying a image on top of the google map that is clickable but not sure if that will take all the events away from the google map.

Do you have any ideas on how it could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a pretty good description of how to do this [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/controls.html#Custom_Controls).

I am pretty sure you can style these guys to look like the standard buttons and you can definitely anchor it to the top right.  When I get a chance I'll give it a try and update with my results.

Update:

I had a chance to try this out and it works ok:

- [Map example with Google style buttons](http://www.cannonade.net/geo.php?test=geo10)
- [Javascript Source](http://www.cannonade.net/geo10.js)

Basically you end up doing very similar things implementing the buttons using GControl or just using absolute positioning of a DIV over the map (as [ChrisB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53487/chris-b) suggested).  So I don't think there is a correct (or easier) approach, it's just a matter of personal preference.  Good luck.

Comment: I believe the Google Control method to be the safest. I have created a control via that mechanism, and it works the best, because the other method requires absolute positioning, which I could not do for the map in my case

Comment: The above links are for **v2**, which as of now is deprecated (the current version is **v3**). A now relevant link for the same topic can be found here:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomExample

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is from 2009 (5 years ago) and links to a deprecated version of Google Maps API.

While searching for the very same question I've found this example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom

```
// Create the DIV to hold the control and
// call the HomeControl() constructor passing
// in this DIV.
var homeControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
var homeControl = new HomeControl(homeControlDiv, map);

homeControlDiv.index = 1;
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(homeControlDiv);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to supplement Cannonade's answer, here's the html/css that a Google Map control uses.  You can replicate the css to make it look just like the real thing.

You could create a formal GControl, or you could just place them over the Google Map with absolute positioning.

Active button:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black; position: absolute; background-color: white; text-align: center; width: 5em; cursor: pointer; right: 15.3em;" title="Show street map">
    <div style="border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(52, 86, 132) rgb(108, 157, 223) rgb(108, 157, 223) rgb(52, 86, 132); border-width: 1px; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">
        Map
    </div>
</div>
```

Inactive button:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black; position: absolute; background-color: white; text-align: center; width: 5em; cursor: pointer; right: 5.1em;" title="Show imagery with street names">
    <div style="border-style: solid; border-color: white rgb(176, 176, 176) rgb(176, 176, 176) white; border-width: 1px; font-size: 12px;">
        Hybrid
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE:** There is also an extension in the Google Maps Utility Library that can accomplish this - [ExtMapTypeControl](http://gmaps-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/extmaptypecontrol/1.3/docs/reference.html)

Comment: +1 Thanks Chris ;), this saved me some time working out how to style these guys. I have gone the absolute position route before, so I was interested in the trying the GControl thing. I'll post back when I have had a chance to do it.

Comment: Thanks I tried this mechanism and it works well in my tests, but in the end I went down the GControl mechanism, as I didn't have to worry about positioning the map specifically.

Comment: @Cannonade - no problem - I just copied it straight out of Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, this is how I did it, Create a button and give it the below styling

id="my_button"

```
 #my_button{
          position:absolute;
          bottom:2%;
          color: #fff;
          background-color: #4d90fe;
          padding: 11px;

          border: 1px solid transparent;
          border-radius: 2px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

          outline: none;
          box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
          alignment-baseline:central;
          width:90%;
          left:5%;
          text-align:center;
          text-decoration:none;


          margin:0px auto;}


         #my_button:hover{
             background-color:#3B6EC2;}
```

Comment: when I select the full-screen map mode, I am unable to see the button.

Comment: google update: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26597355/4425004  for placing a button over a map

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery it looks like this:
first, create a function, that will return your element

```
function myButton(){
    var btn = $('<div class="my-button"></div>');
    btn.bind('click', function(){
        // logic here...
        alert('button clicked!');
    });
    return btn[0];
}
```

and after map was created you need to attach your button to it:

```
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(myButton());
```