# Add a back button in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

My current implementation is, when I open the html via browser it zooms to North America map with 4 markers. On click of the markers, the maps is zoomed to that location with few more markers added. Now I would like to add a back button so when the button is clicked it should take me to the initial maps page with 4 markers. 
Your help is much appreciated.
Thanks,
Chitra

Comment: Anything you tried?

Comment: yep, I tried to add a home button calling a function to load the home page. But, it always throws me an undefined function error.

Answer (score 0):

The features of Google Maps API that you will need to use are *bounds*. For a rough understanding, imagine providing a top left corner point and a bottom right corner point and just telling the viewport to zoom and track to fit them in. There is a good answer here: [Google Map API v3 — set bounds and center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556921/google-map-api-v3-set-bounds-and-center#2205577)

As for how you implement the actual button to trigger the feature, that is a separate question and there are many potential solutions. Again, it has already been discussed here: [Put a button on top of a google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068158/put-a-button-on-top-of-a-google-map)

Comment: Thanks @Martin. But I want the existing markers to disappear and the page loaded back to only with 4 markers (home page).

Comment: I have made the initial loading of the page as a function. Added a Home button so as and when the button is clicked, it calls the initial loading funcion. This way I got the back button implementation working.